# SQLAlchemy Mapping Multiple Columns to Single Property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm building a web application in Python 3 using Flask & SQLAlchemy (via Flask-SQLAlchemy; with either MySQL or SQLite), and I've run into a situation where I'd like to reference a single property on my model class that encapsulates multiple columns in my database.  I'm pretty well versed in MySQL, but this is my first real foray into SQLAlchemy beyond the basics.  Reading the docs, scouring SO, and searching Google have led me to two possible solutions: Hybrid attributes ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)) or Composite columns ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html)).

My question is what are the implications of using each of these, and which of these is the appropriate solution to my situation?  I've included example code below that's a snippet of what I'm doing.

---

Background: I'm developing an application to track & sort photographs, and have a DB table in which I store the metadata for these photos, including when the picture was taken.  Since photos are taken in a specific place, the taken date & time have an associated timezone.  As SQL has a notoriously love/hate relationship with timezones, I've opted to record when the photo was taken in two columns: a datetime storing the date & time and a string storing the timezone name.  (I'd like to sidestep the inevitable debate about how to store timezone aware dates & times in SQL, please.)  What I would like is a single parameter on the model class that can I can use to get a proper python datetime object, and that I can also set like any other column.

Here's my table:

```
class Photo(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'photos'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    taken_dt = db.Column(db.datetime, nullable=False)
    taken_tz = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    ...
```

Here's what I have using a hybrid parameter (added to the above class, datetime/pytz code is psuedocode):

```
    @hybrid_parameter
    def taken(self):
        return datetime.datetime(self.taken_dt, self.taken_tz)

    @taken.setter(self, dt):
        self.taken_dt = dt
        self.taken_tz = dt.tzinfo
```

From there I'm not exactly sure what else I need in the way of a `@taken.expression` or `@taken.comparator`, or why I'd choose one over the other.

Here's what I have using a composite column (again, added to the above class, datetime/pytz code is psuedocode):

```
    taken = composite(DateTimeTimeZone._make, taken_dt, taken,tz)

class DateTimeTimeZone(object):

    def __init__(self, dt, tz):
        self.dt = dt
        self.tz = tz

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, dt, tz):
        return DateTimeTimeZone(dt, tz)

    @classmethod
    def from_dt(cls, dt):
        return DateTimeTimeZone(dt, dt.tzinfo)

    def __composite_values__(self):
        return (self.dt, self.tz)

    def value(self): 
        #This is here so I can get the actual datetime.datetime object
        return datetime.datetime(self.dt, self.tz)
```

It would seem that this method has a decent amount of extra overhead, and I can't figure out a way to set it like I would any other column directly from a datetime.datetime object without instantiating the value object first using `.from_dt`.

Any guidance on if I'm going down the wrong path here would be welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Look into hooking up an `AttributeEvent` to your column and have it check for `datetime` instances which have a `tz` attribute set and then return a `DateTimeTimeZone` object. If you look at the [SQLAlchemy docs for Attribute Events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_2/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents) you can see that you can tell `SQLAlchemy` to listen to an attribute-set event and call your code on that. In there you can do any modification to the value being set as you like. You can't however access other attributes of the class at that time. I haven't tried this in combination with composites yet, so I don't know if this will be called **before or after** the type-conversion of the composite. You'd have to try.

edit: Its all about what you want to achieve though. The `AttributeEvent` can help you with your data consistency, while the `hybrid_property` and friends will make querying easier for you. You should use each one for it's intended use-case.

## More detailed discussion on the differences between the various solutions:

`hybrid_attribute` and `composite` are two completely different beasts. To understand `hybrid_attribute` one first has to understand what a `column_property` is and can do.

## 1) column_property

This one is placed on a mapper and can contain any `selectable`. So if you put an concrete sub-select into a `column_property` you can access it **read-only** as if it were a concrete column. The calculation is done on the fly. You can even use it to search for entries. `SQLAlchemy` will construct the right select containing your sub-select for you.

### Example:

```
class User(Base):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = Column(Unicode)
   last_name = Column(Unicode)

   name = column_property(first_name + ' ' + last_name)
   category = column_property(select([CategoryName.name])
                              .select_from(Category.__table__
                                           .join(CategoryName.__table__))
                              .where(Category.user_id == id))

db.query(User).filter(User.name == 'John Doe').all()

db.query(User).filter(User.category == 'Paid').all()
```

As you can see, this can simplify a lot of code, but one has to be careful to think of the performance implications.

## 2) hybrid_method and hybrid_attribute

A `hybrid_attribute` is just like a `column_property` but can call a different code-path when you are in an **instance context**. So you can have the `selectable` on the class level but a different implementation on the instance level. With a `hybrid_method` you can even parametrize both sides.

## 3) composite_attribute

This is what enables you to combine multiple concrete columns to a logical single one. You have to write a class for this logical column so that `SQLAlchemy` can extract the correct values from there and use it in the selects. This integrates neatly in the query framework and should not impose any additional problems. In my experience the use-cases for composite columns are rather rare. Your use-case seems fine. For modification of values you can always use `AttributeEvents`. If you want to have the whole instance available you'd have to have a `MapperEvent` called before flush. This certainly works, as I used this to implement a completely transparent *Audit Trail* tracking system which stored every value changed in every table in a separate set of tables.

Comment: thanks for concise comparison, it helps a lot!  I am definitely looking for a solution that allows setting & getting as transparently as possible, and ideally filtering, too.  The attribute event alternative is one I hadn't stumbled on and looks intriguing, I'll have to investigate further.  But it seems to me that the hybrid property approach gets closest to what I'm looking for, as it will allow me to get and set the taken date using existing datetime objects rather than needing to build a new value class to wrap them.